# react native - onPress get Flatlist detailed information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native Flatlist from [react native elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/lists.html). 
What I want to do is when I click on each row, I want to navigate to a new screen and get detailed information. 
[image]

So for example, if I click on `AmyFarha` I want to access to her `email` and `phoneNumber` in the new screen.

Below is the code. I have added email and phoneNumber field.

```
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President',
    email: 'amy@amy.com',
    phoneNumber: '1-808-9999'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    email: 'chris@chris.com',
    phoneNumber: '1-808-8888'
  },
  ... // more items
]

<List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>
  {
    list.map((l) => (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
        key={l.name}
        title={l.name}
      />
    ))
  }
</List>
```

Comment: Why dont you use touchablehighlight

Comment: what navigation you are using ?

Comment: @Nima createDrawerNavigator and createStackNavigator does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

In component list item use expand to show user detail, like this:

```
handleExpand = () => {
    this.setState({expand: !this.state.expand})
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleExpand}>
   {this.state.expand ? (<ViewExpand/>) : (<ViewNormal/>)}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: hum.. I don't get it. It would be nice if you could elaborate it bit more thanks tho :)

Comment: handleExpand is a function that gets called every time you click the row item
So, inside the function the state is set, which will just revert whatever the expand value it currently has. That is, if it has true value, it sets that to false and vice-versa. So, everytime the state is expanded, the ViewExpand component gets rendered. The code inside TouchableOpacity is ternary operator, which will run ViewExpand if this.state.expand is true and null if this.state.expand is false!

Answer (score 0):

```
handleTouchItem = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("forward page do you want", item);
}
 <ListItem
        onPress={() => this.handleTouchItem(item)}
        roundAvatar
        avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
        key={l.name}
        title={l.name}
      />
```

Comment: Can you please add a short description?

Comment: `handleTouchItem` is the function, you know **es6** rule mostly in react native using arrow function, and the `ListItem` component, you just call that function using properties `onPress()` with the parameter `item`,  parameter `item`  is come from your `list.map((l) => (` just change from `i` to `item` for make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like this:

```
 <View>
              <FlatList
                  data={list}
                  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                      <CustomItemComponent item={item} onPress={this.props.onItemPress}/>
                  )}
                  numColumns={2}
                  />
</View>
```

And you can create a new component `CustomItemComponent` with item as a prop. In this new component you can use `name`, `title` or any other property.

Comment: thanks so much for the comments but I am really new to react native so it would really help if you could provide the full code! Again really appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Hello Kirimi, you can found a good tutorial here: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6
And the documentation from `react-native` here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: yea I saw this but this doesn't tell how to get detailed information `onPress`